# Index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 while trying to maximize a function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to set up a dynamic programming problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


alpha = 1
beta = 0.5
nabla = 0.5
A = 1
delta = 1
rho = 1

grid_max=10
grid_size=250
grid = np.linspace(1e-5, grid_max, grid_size)

def u(x):
    return np.log((x[0]**alpha)*x[0]**(beta+nabla))

def f(x):
    return A*x

def k_plus(k,x):
    return f(k)+(1-delta)-x[0]-x[1]

def obj_fun(x,k,v_array):
    """note v_array is our guess of v evaluated at the grid points. 
    we then interpolate in between"""
    v = interp1d(grid, v_array)

    return u(x) + rho*v(k_plus(k,x))

x_prueba = [2,2]
k=10
objetivo = lambda x: (-1)*obj_fun(x,k,np.log(grid))
minimize(objetivo, x0=[0,0], bounds=[(0, None), (0,None)], 
         constraints={"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: -x[0] -  x[1] + 10})
```

The parameters' values are like that for ease of computation but they will be different of course.
The latest error I get is:
Iteration limit exceeded

I appreciate any help, and please let me know if the question is ill-pose in order to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Python 3.6.9 and scipy 1.3.3. Your code runs fine, except that the minimize operation does not converge. This is because you start with `x0 = [0, 0]`, which is used in `u(x)` where `log(0)` is then calculated. If you provide a different x0 (up to [5, 4], after that it stops converging), it works. With a little re-write (e.g., you do not need interp1d as all you are interpolating through is a natural logarithm), this looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def u(x):
    return np.log(x[0] ** alpha * x[0] ** (beta + nabla))


def k_plus(k, x):
    return A * k + 1 - delta - x[0] - x[1]


def obj_fun(x, k, v_array):
    return -u(x) - rho * np.log(k_plus(k, x))


alpha = 1
beta = 0.5
nabla = 0.5
A = 1
delta = 1
rho = 1

grid_max = 10
grid_size = 250
grid = np.linspace(1e-5, grid_max, grid_size)

x_prueba = [2, 2]
k = 10

res = minimize(obj_fun, x0=[5, 4], args=(k, np.log(grid)),
               bounds=((0, np.inf), (0, np.inf)),
               constraints={"type": "ineq",
                            "fun": lambda x: -x[0] - x[1] + 10})
print(res.success)
print(res.x)
```

This prints

```
True
[6.66662927 0.        ]
```